# continuity on open sets

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f:A\rightarrow\Bbb R$, $A\subset\Bbb R$ and any  $c \in \Bbb R $

If  $E^-=\{x \in A :f(x)< c\}$ and $E^+=\{x\in A:f(x)>c\}$ are open sets, then $f:A\rightarrow \Bbb R$ is continuous.

Comment: What are you asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a < b$.

$E^{+}_a = \{x \in A : f(x) > a\} = f^{-1}((a, \infty))$

and

$E^-_b = \{x \in A : f(x) < b\} = f^{-1}((-\infty, b))$

are open by the assumption. Hence

$f^{-1}((a,b)) = f^{-1}((a, \infty) \cap (-\infty, b)) = f^{-1}((a,\infty)) \cap f^{-1}((-\infty, b))$

is open. All open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is a union of open sets of the form $(a,b)$. $f^{-1}(U)$ is open. The inverse image of any open set under $f$ is open. Hence $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a < b$.
Then $f^{-1}((a, b))$ is open by the assumption.
Any open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is a union of subsets of the form $(a, b)$.
Hence $f^{-1}(U)$ is open.
Hence $f$ is continuous.